# Unable to replace NGinx 495/496 Error Page

Tags: configuration, nginx

I am trying to change the site which get's returned to the client when no certificate has been sent. My config is below:

```
    server {
error_log /tmp/error.log;
    listen        443;
    ssl on;
    server_name router.local;
    ssl_certificate      /tmp/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /tmp/server.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /tmp/ca.crt;
    ssl_trusted_certificate  /tmp/ca.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_verify_depth 1;
        ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    location /error_serve {
     root   /sites/error;
     error_page 400 402 403 404 = /error_serve/5xx.html;
    }
    location / {

     proxy_buffer_size   128k;
     proxy_buffers   4 256k;
     proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
     proxy_pass  http://192.168.1.1/;
     proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
     error_page 400 500 502 503 504 = /error_serve/5xx.html;
     error_page 495 496 = /error_serve/cert_wrong.html;
    }
}
```

All other error pages are working, only the 495 and 496 return the standard pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL handshake happens before any HTTP request, so there is no known `location` at the time. In this case nginx just picks up configuration from the first one (which is `location /error_serve` in your configuration).

Comment: So I need to move location /error_serve after the location /

Comment: Can you tell me how to solve it correctly? The file displayed is not the one from error_serve but the default

Comment: As you have said already, you can interchange your locations. But as it seems to me, the right solution is to put `error_page` directive on server level.

Comment: I added a error_page 495 496 = /error_serve/cert_wrong.html; after the ssl verify depth. Now I am getting 404 error.

Comment: Do you actually have `/sites/error/error_serve/cert_wrong.html`?